# Why is the Trustpilot Widget not Loading in Next.js intermittently?

Tags: javascript, next.js, trustpilot

I'm facing an intermittent issue with loading the Trustpilot widget in my Next.js application. Sometimes it loads perfectly, but other times it fails to load.

I've already searched a lot about it and read the Trustpilot documentation about how to integrate it, but whatever I did to solve this problem was for the birds.

We had another website that was based on WordPress; we didn't have such a problem there, but in this project that is based on Next.js, we face this problem.

This is the script that I have in the `_app.js` file inside the `head` tag:

```
<Head>
    
    <script
      type="text/javascript"
      src="//widget.trustpilot.com/bootstrap/v5/tp.widget.bootstrap.min.js"
      async
    ></script>
</Head>
```

This is the Trustpilot `Widget` code that I loged the `window.trustpilot`, when it is not loading `console.log(window.trustpilot)` log `undefined`:

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef } from "react";
const TrustBox = ({ mode}) => {
  const option = {
    horizontal: {
      "data-template-id": "the id",
      "data-businessunit-id": "the id",
      "data-style-height": "150px",
      "data-style-width": "100%",
      "data-theme": "white",
      "data-text-size":"30px",

    },
    carousel: {
      "data-template-id": "the id",
      "data-businessunit-id": "the id",
      "data-style-height": "250px",
      "data-style-width": "100%",
      "data-theme": "white",
      "data-stars": "5",
      "data-review-languages": "en",
    },
  };
  const ref = useRef(null);
  useEffect(() => {
    if (window.Trustpilot) {
      console.log('loaded') //return the modules
      window.Trustpilot.loadFromElement(ref.current, true);
    }
    else{
      console.log(window.trustpilot) //undeifined
    }
  }, [mode]);
  return (
    <div
      ref={ref}
      data-locale="en-GB"
      {...option[mode]}
    />
  );
};
export default TrustBox;
```

I have attached the screenshots too:

[image: when it is not loading]
[image: when it is loading]

Comment: If there's no error to share and you can't provide a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) then this question will likely be closed, as we could only guess at what's going on. "Intermittently" can mean "race condition." Your effect only checks for `window.Trustpilot` once, if the JS loads after that check, it looks like nothing will happen. Get in the habit of debugging your own code with `console.log`, which might help you ask a more specific question.

Comment: `window.trustpilot` will always be undefined because there's a typo in the lowercase `t`. But you should google for how to wait for a script to load with React - that is your most likely issue here

Comment: even I `console.log(window.Trustpilot)` it logs `undefined`